# Convert to Entity Query Drupal 8

Tags: 8, database, entities

I want to get the created column from the file managed table of the node field which stores file.Can we have entity query for the same.

```
SELECT file_usage.id AS file_usage_id, node_field_data.nid AS nid, file_managed_node__field_image.fid AS file_managed_node__field_image_fid
FROM 
node_field_data node_field_data
LEFT JOIN node__field_image node__field_image ON node_field_data.nid = node__field_image.entity_id 
LEFT JOIN file_managed file_managed_node__field_image ON node__field_image.field_image_target_id = file_managed_node__field_image.fid
LEFT JOIN file_usage file_usage ON node_field_data.nid = file_usage.id AND file_usage.type = 'node'
WHERE (( (node_field_data.status = '1') AND (node_field_data.type IN  ('article')) AND (file_managed_node__field_image.changed <= 1473325611+157766400) ))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not query file usage with entity query, it is not entity data.

You can also not do reverse joins or load specific data. Entity query gives you entity IDs, which you need to load, and then from that get the data you want.

Meaning, to do what you are doing in an enitty query, you need to build an entity query that gives you the nodes you want, then load them, then get the referenced file and then get the created value from that.

Answer (score 1):

About the need to load the nodes to have access to the referenced file, maybe it's not necessary.
You can access the referenced entity this way :

```
$query->condition('field_referenced_entity.entity.field_of_referenced_entity', 'value');
```

For exemple : this condition is about a tag (referenced entity) with the value 'cats', for his field 'name'.

```
$query->condition('field_tags.entity.name', 'cats');
```

But it's working for entity reference, I don't know if this will work with File reference... (maybe in combination with Media).